# pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval can't work

Tags: point-cloud-library

when it is running at sor.filter(). the program looks like to be hanged.
and no error.

I believe that these is something wrong with the pcd file.because it works well with the pcd data provided by PCL . My pcd file was saved from Kinect2. But I can't find the difference between them.

```
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> > cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer(
new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("Point Cloud Viewer"));
viewer->setCameraPosition(0.0, 0.0, -2.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile("table_scene_lms400.pcd",*cloud);
//pcl::io::loadPCDFile("test.pcd",*cloud);
pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ> sor;
sor.setMeanK(50);
sor.setStddevMulThresh(1);
pcl::PointCloud < pcl::PointXYZ >::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
sor.setInputCloud(cloud);
sor.filter(*cloud_filtered);
viewer->addPointCloud(cloud_filtered,"cloud");
```

Answer (score 0):

At least, I found there are lots of Points' coordinate is[0,0,0] in my pcd file.And that's the problem. I tried to romove them by a passthrough filter . And the resualt is exciting. But I want to get a better way to romove these points.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to remove finite and null points from pointclouds, it is based on [PCL Conditional removal](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_conditional_removal.html) class and [isFinite()](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/point__tests_8h_source.html#l00053) :

```
PointCloudPtr null_filter(const PointCloudPtr cloud_in)
{
    PointCloudPtr cloud_out(new PointCloud);
    PointCloudPtr temp(new PointCloud);

    // build the condition
    pcl::ConditionOr<PointT>::Ptr range_cond(new pcl::ConditionOr<PointT>());
    range_cond->addComparison(pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::ConstPtr(new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("x", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, 0.0)));
    range_cond->addComparison(pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::ConstPtr(new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("x", pcl::ComparisonOps::LT, 0.0)));

    range_cond->addComparison(pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::ConstPtr(new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("y", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, 0.0)));
    range_cond->addComparison(pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::ConstPtr(new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("y", pcl::ComparisonOps::LT, 0.0)));

    range_cond->addComparison(pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::ConstPtr(new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("z", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, 0.0)));
    range_cond->addComparison(pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::ConstPtr(new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("z", pcl::ComparisonOps::LT, 0.0)));

    // build the filter
    pcl::ConditionalRemoval<PointT> condrem;
    condrem.setCondition(range_cond);
    condrem.setInputCloud(cloud_in);

    // apply filter
    condrem.filter(*cloud_out);

    pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::iterator del = cloud_out->points.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < cloud_out->points.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!pcl::isFinite<PointT>(cloud_out->points[i]))
        {
            //      PCL_WARN("normals[%d] is not finite\n", i);
            cloud_out->points.erase(del + i);
        }
    }
    std::vector<int> indices;
    pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*cloud_out, *temp, indices);

    return temp;
}
```